# Is "high impedance" state analogy with "superposition" state?

Tags: quantum-information, voltage, superposition, quantum-states

In digital logic (classical bit), there's a state called "1" which is a defined high voltage, for example 2.7 V - 5.0 V. To achieve it we must connect it to VCC.

And "0" which is a low voltage, for example 0 V until 0.8 V. To achieve it we must connect it to GND.

And there's another state called "high impedance" or "disconnected" state in which those wires are not connected neither to GND nor VCC. It's called floating wire.

So can we say floating wire's state is in superposition like how quantum particle such as photon and electron in superposition? Or is "high impedance" state same as superposition state?

If yes, then why we still need qubit?

If no, then why "high impedance" state that I mentioned above and qubit state in superposition state are not analogy?

Note: I'm sorry I still don't know much about qubit but I'm sure I know classical bit, as a Computer Engineer student I need to learn more about qubit so I can understand about qubit information teleportation.

Comment: Why was this closed for lacking details or clarity? It is perfectly clear to me. Is it because *theorists* don't understand what a high impedance state is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The high impedance output isn't in superposition. It possesses a well-defined voltage even though the output doesn't control it. Knowledge of leakage current and history may be used to predict it. The measured voltage may be intermediate, neither one nor zero.

A qbit in superposition is quite different. For one thing, no measurement will report an intermediate state: it'll be either one or zero. If it's truly in superposition, the result of measurement is unpredictable.